# How can I get the youtube webcam widget to upload to one account using API?

Tags: youtube-api

I've embedded the youtube upload widget to allow users to record themselves using their webcams. They are answering some questions as part of an online application. I want to take these webcam recordings and upload them to one central youtube account hosted by my organization.

Is this possible?  Any links to how this can be accomplished are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supported/possible, and not recommended, for the reasons outlined at http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community_15.html