# redirect_uri_mismatch error Google API v3 .NET

Tags: .net, api, youtube

My problem is very similar to this one: [Keep getting Error: redirect_uri_mismatch using youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059177/keep-getting-error-redirect-uri-mismatch-using-youtube-api-v3)
But no one seems to be able to find a right solution.

my app is hosted in: test . com:61156/Media/Upload
in my local computer , I had to modify the hosts file, all to get this AUTH 2.0 working, but still anything I do I keep getting redirect_uri_mismatch no matter what I do.

I am getting this error:

The redirect URI in the request:local host:12451/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI.

---

This is how my Client ID for web application is setup

**REDIRECT URIS**  http://test.com:61156/

**JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS** 
http://test.com:61156/

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `AuthCallback` string in your `FlowMetadata` implementation, for example:

```
    public override string AuthCallback
    {
        get
        {
            return "/oauth2callback";
        }
    }
```

Note that this should be the *relative path* so that the URL will match one of the URLs you specified in the **Client ID for web application** you created in the Google Developers Console.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on your answer? I'm facing the same problem, but don't have any `FlowMetadata` implementation. Thanks