# YouTube Data V3 API not recognizing localhost url for redirect uri, why?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to test out the **YouTube Data API V3** to Upload a Video to YouTube in C# using the [example code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video) supplied.

I am using the **OAuth2** method. I have generated a Client ID / Secret successfully.

The issue I am having is that created a standard C# MVC ASP.NET project, and every time I run it it might say for example http://localhost:5151/.

We are on a private network so I usually have to use something like **ngrok** to receive anything from the outside world being sent directly to my server / machine.

Anyways, where was I? So every time I run my application it says in my url box http://localhost:5151/ *but* when I attempt to run the code in the sample I provided above, it fails to validate me as a user because they claim that the redirect uri's I have set up in the Google API dashboard are not the same as the url being used.

So for example, in my Google API Dashboard redirect uri list I have http://localhost:5151/. But the google misdirect uri error that comes back claims that I am running on http://localhost:6163/ .

So I think wait, that must be just a fluke. So I run my application again and now in the url it again says what I would assume it should: http://localhost:5151/, but I *again* get the same google error_mismatch_redirect_uri error but this time with a **different** port: http://localhost:6621/  !!

I'm not sure what settings are on our servers but it looks like in the background my application is starting up on some random port every time and **thus** google thinks the redirect uri's dont match! What can I do to fix this? Am I missing something trivial here?

**UPDATE:**
Tried using http://localhost:8080 per their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). Still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, after hours of searching I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794316/7010468. Apparently you have to put http://localhost/authorize/ in your list of redirect-uris...